# React JSX - dynamic html attribute

Tags: reactjs, jsx

In JSX, we can indicate attribute value dynamically like:

```
<div className={this.state.className}>This is a div.</div>
```

Is it possible to indicate attribute (including attribute name and attribute value) dynamically? Like:

```
const value = emptyValue ? "" : "value='test'";
<input {value} />
```

That means, once `emptyValue` is true, "input" tag should not include "value" attribute (value="" is different from no value attribute, as one is show empty in input field, another is show existing text in input field).

Comment: Why not `<input value={emptyValue ? "" : "test"}>`?

Comment: @AndrewLi you are correct. While I want once `emptyValue ` is true, "value" attribute should not exist in the "input".

Comment: You could of course make it an object like: `const props = { value: "test", otherProp: "blah" }` and then `<input {...props}>`

Comment: `value={emptyValue ?  null : "test"}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ES6 object expansion only works for objects. Therefore to generate a dynamic attribute, try something like this:

```
const value = emptyValue ? {} : { value: 'test' }
<a  {...value} ></a>
```

Note `value` will always be an object.

Comment: But it's a string, not an object.

Comment: `let obj = {}; if(emptyValue) { obj.value = "test" }`

`<a  {...obj} ></a>`
That is what I am talking about

Answer (score 1):

you can insert whole element in `if` statement in render function, but before `return` like this:

```
render() {

var input = (<input />);
if (!emptyValue) {
    input = (<input value='test'/>)
}

return (
    <div>
        {input}
    </div>
    )
}
```